# Simplest ajax form not working when it should

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a very basic ajax call in wp-admin area where the form sends the Post ID. This value will be used to update_post_meta().

**Simply stuff right?** Well, I've been on this task all yesterday without success. Could you help me solve this today so that I can spend my Saturday night in a pub drinking a pint?

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#submitform').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var TheForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=UpdateMeta",
    data: TheForm,
    success:function(data){
        // Help, what do I do here to make this work?
});

return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="submitform" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" />
    <button type="send" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn"></button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function UpdateMeta(){

    $post_id = $_POST["postid"];

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'helloworld', $post_id);

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_UpdateMeta', 'UpdateMeta');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_UpdateMeta', 'UpdateMeta');
```

Comment: Do you see the request happening in browser's dev tools? Any JS errors showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been investing some quality time (and headaches) with WP ajax so I understand where you are coming from.

In all honesty, it could be anything from an error in your JS code or something completely bizarre, like:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_UpdateMeta', 'UpdateMeta');
```

Should be changed to:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_updatemeta', 'UpdateMeta');
```

... to remove the capitals because by some reason, it was causing an issue when I was playing around with adding action to `wp_ajax`.

The following will work for you, I just tested it on a custom admin page. Note that I added a div with class `feedback` in case you want to return any data there for testing, or to the user.

html

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="submitform" />
       <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" />
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updatemeta" />
       <button type="send" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="feedback"></div>
```

php

```
function updatemeta(){

    $post_id = $_POST["postid"];

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'helloworld', $post_id);

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_updatemeta', 'updatemeta');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updatemeta', 'updatemeta');
```

JS

```
jQuery('#submitform').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

var submitform = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // URL to admin-ajax.php
        data: submitform,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery(".feedback").html(data); // empty div to show returned data
        }
    });

    return false;
    }
```

Enjoy your beer. :)

Comment: Just need to add 'action' in JS to link it with wp_ajax. Like the way you made separate ajaxSubmit function; looks pretty neat.

Comment: @MohammadMursaleen No this user's code had more problems than adding the action value. I tested it initially and couldn't find the cause, like I said, it could have been just a matter of removing capitals. We are talking about jQuery WP Ajax... anything is possible to fail.

Comment: I mean in your answer I think action is missing.

Comment: Oh right, no it is added within the form: <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updatemeta" />

Comment: Got it! wasn't aware of declaring action that way. +1 for introducing some new stuff. Thanks!

Comment: My guess though is that the problem with the original code is with the `url` in the ajax - should use `url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>?action=UpdateMeta"`. (The capitals thing, although unusual, shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: @bonger The code posted by the OP already had the URL with ?action=UpdateMeta...

Comment: It was not using the echo `admin_url()` that I meant to point out, that at a guess his system isn't installed at document root so the call doesn't reach it, but I could be wrong!..